# Using dispatch tables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this chunk of code, one sample is `$dispatch='TC_12'`:

```
foreach($this->dispatch as $dispatch){
   $data['$dispatch'] = $this->genericQuery($dispatch, '1');
}
```

`$this->dispatch` is an array of **dispatch tables**. However, I wrote the method `genericQuery()` to generate dynamically generated queries. Everything works fine, except when I analyse the `JSON` object returned I saw:

```
`"$dispatch":["Hello world"]}`
```

However I would like to see `"TC_12":["Hello world"]`.
How can I obtain that result? I thought the string would get replaced at `$data['$dispatch']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables only get replaced in double-quoted strings. Dollar signs are treated as literals in single-quoted strings. (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.) In this case, though, there's no need for quotes at all. Try this:

```
foreach($this->dispatch as $dispatch){
   $data[$dispatch] = $this->genericQuery($dispatch, '1');
}
```